# Trying to play sound with animation but keep getting "Thread 1 Signal SIGABRT" error in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiimageview

My code used to work perfectly when I used to just have an animation. However, now I tried to add sound to the animation also, I've implemented the sound as well as I can however now every time the app runs it shuts down and gives me the **SIGABRT** error, here is my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController {

}
- (IBAction)Button {

    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SoundID);
}    

-(IBAction)startanimating{
    animatedimage.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo1.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo2.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo3.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo4.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo5.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo6.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo7.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo8.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo9.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo10.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo11.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo12.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo13.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo14.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo15.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo16.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo17.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo18.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo19.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo20.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo22.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo23.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo24.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo25.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo26.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo52.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo51.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo50.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo49.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo48.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo47.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo46.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo45.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo44.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo43.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo42.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo41.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo40.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo39.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo38.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo37.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo36.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo35.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo34.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo33.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo32.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo31.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo30.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo29.jpg"],
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"ALambo28.jpg"], nil];        
    [animatedimage setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
    animatedimage.animationDuration = 1.2;
    [animatedimage startAnimating];        
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SoundRev" ofType:@"m4a"]];        
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)buttonURL, &SoundID);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

Here is the (.h) also:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{        
    IBOutlet UIImageView *animatedimage;        
    SystemSoundID SoundID;        
}

-(IBAction)startanimating;

@end
```

Comment: Turn breakpoints on and see where exactly it breaks.

Comment: try adding an [exception breakpoint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/exception-breakpoint-in-xcode) to your project to diagnose the error.

Comment: I added one and it highlights this line  NSURL *buttonURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath: [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SoundRev" ofType:@"m4a"]];

Comment: Just fixed the error. Something was up with the sound file. changed it to mp3 and it started to work perfectly. I found out because of the exception breakpoint so thanks everybody! :D

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID in quite a while. I suggest switching your code to use AVAudioPlayer instead. That API is both more flexible and easier to use.